# Why I get incorrect dimention, when I'm using cbind to convert my list to matix?

Tags: r

I have list of matrices, and I want to select only second column of them and  put them together to make new matrix.
But when I do this, the dimension of my matrix has one extra column. Does someone knows why and have would solve it?

Here is my data and effort:

```
ismr4   # list of matrices.
> length(ismr4)                                         
[1] 733
```

Code to select second column of every matrix and put them together

```
for(i in 1:length(ismr4)){
        mir_exp<-cbind(ismr4[[i]][,2],mir_exp)
        mir_exp}


> dim(mir_exp)
[1] 863 734
```

But I would expect to have dimension:

```
> dim(mir_exp)
[1] 863 733
```

Comment: You need `i`'s on `mir_exp` in `mir_exp<-cbind(ismr4[[i]][,2],mir_exp)` for it to bind on every iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fake data setup..

```
> a <- matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 5)
> b <- c <- a
> foo <- list(a,b,c)
> a
        [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
[1,] -0.3102  0.6961 -0.8455 0.6751  1.097
[2,] -0.6147 -2.3394  0.5483 0.8374 -2.013
```

then you can do a one-liner with `sapply` like ...

```
> sapply(foo, function(x) x[,2])
        [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
[1,]  0.6961  0.6961  0.6961
[2,] -2.3394 -2.3394 -2.3394
```

which apply the anonymous function to all the elements of your list (extracts the second column) and "simplify" the results (here it returns a `matrix`, that is what you want).

Answer (score 3):

Two issues. Using a for loop you would have needed to pre-assign `mir_exp` to some structure and it is probably the source of the extra row. You should look at "

```
 head(mir_exp)
```

Second issue: Unlike the use of functions, you do not want to evaluate the intended return object inside the for-loop. The assignment is occurring in the same frame as the for-loop was called from, in this case in the global environment.

If you want the second column from a list of matrices then:

```
 lapply( mlist, "[" , TRUE, 2 )
```

And to bind them together column-wise:

```
> do.call( cbind, lapply( foo, "[" , TRUE, 2 ) )
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 2.447088 2.447088 2.447088
[2,] 2.653021 2.653021 2.653021
```